# $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematical-physics

Today in my mathematical quantum theory lecture our professor told us without any explanation, that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ it follows that $f\in C_{\infty}=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R})\mid \lim_{R\to\infty} \sup_{∣∣x∣∣>R} ∣f(x)∣=0\}$, where we consider $R$ as a radius.

Is there an easy way to see that? For me it is not quite obvious. What informations do I get from the conditions that tell me, that this kind of functions are vanishing at infinity?

Comment: ${}$ What is $R$?

Comment: I interpret the thesis as $f(\pm \infty)=0$. As $f(x)= f(0) + \int_0^x f'(z)dz$, with the said hypotheses, the limit  $f(+\infty)$ exists finite trivially. If it does not vanish, then  $f$ cannot belong to $L^1$.